# Firebase Task<AuthResult> task.isSuccessful always returning false

Tags: android, firebase

I was doing Firebase Authentication with email & password in Android Studio, so I followed all setup steps in [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth) (added Firebase my project, add the dependencies, enable Email/Password sign-in). Also, I just copied the [sample project](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/5b3e835d1e87b78567c2558f631bfad769bc87e6/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/java/EmailPasswordActivity.java#L67-L68) from their documentation because I just wanted to see if it works. But, when I click the Register button I get the "Authentication failed." toast. That means the task.isSuccessful() returned false..does someone know why this keeps happening? I'm pretty sure problem lies somewhere in Firebase/Android Studio since I copied 99% of their code.

```
 mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication success.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: How far are you in the process? Have you added firebase to your project with the json file they create for you?

Comment: As Martin said, you might wanna check if the .json file is set properly. And you can consider use AndroidStudio's `Tools` -> `Firebase` that can help you setup step by step.

Comment: I have download the google-services.json file (if that is what you mean), but I have no idea where to put it in my project.

Comment: In the top left corner you can see Android with icon next to it, click that and switch it to project. Now you should be able to see an app folder. Place it here so it is next to build gradle

Comment: You can have a look at my project [here](https://github.com/grrigore/Trip-Back-up) I use Firebase Auth. **LE:** as I know the password has to be at least 6 characters long.

Comment: did you enable firebase email and password sign in from your Firebase console? and try to remove the context from the callback, leave it like this .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()... , also, check the verbose logcat, you might find why is not connecting to auth

Comment: I tried putting the 'google-services.json' where you instructed, but I still have the 'Authentication failed' message. Yes, I have enabled Firebase Email/Password sign in. And I tried removing the context from the callback, but the problem still persists.
Also, I considered using the Firebase Assistant but can't reach Step 2 since it keeps adding 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0' which results a gradle build failure so I just replaced it with 16.0.1.

Comment: EDIT: It's working now! I really don't know what happened, but I just restarted my Android Studio and now it's working! Maybe it just had to be restarted in order to read 'google-services.json' file. Thank you for your help guys :)